# Is it required to assign default value to variable?

Tags: go, default, default-value

In Go, when a variable is declared it is initialized with zero value as described in the specification.

http://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value

But is it good coding practice to make use of this property and do not explicitly initialize your variable if it needs to initialized with the default value.

for example in the following example

http://play.golang.org/p/Mvh_zwFkOu

```
package main

import "fmt"

type B struct {
    isInit bool
    Greeting string
}

func (b *B) Init() {
    b.isInit = true
    b.Greeting = "Thak you for your time"
}

func (b *B) IsInitialized() bool {
    return b.isInit
}

func main() {
    var b B
    if !b.IsInitialized(){
        b.Init()
    }
    fmt.Println(b.Greeting)
}
```

The program relies on the default value of boolean to be false.

Comment: Additionally, if you run golint it will suggest that you drop the extra assignment because it is the default value.  It's a good tool for getting started with Go's style.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As everyone says, specification is clear here: all memory is initialised (zeroed). You *should* take advantage of this as standard packages do. In particular, it allows you to rely on "default constructor" for your own types and often skip `New() *T` kind of functions in favour of `&T{}`.

Many types in standard packages take advantage of this, some examples:

[http.Client](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client)

> A Client is an HTTP client. **Its zero value** (DefaultClient) is a usable client that uses DefaultTransport.

And then you will find `var DefaultClient = &Client{}` declared in the package.

[http.Server](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server)

> A Server defines parameters for running an HTTP server. **The zero value** for Server is a valid configuration.

[bytes.Buffer](http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer)

> A Buffer is a variable-sized buffer of bytes with Read and Write methods. **The zero value** for Buffer is an empty buffer ready to use.

This is great, because you can just do `var buf bytes.Buffer` and start using it. As a consequence of this you will also often see boolean member variables to be used in a "negated" form – for example `InsecureSkipVerify` in [`tls.Config`](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config) is not called `Verify`, because the default behaviour wouldn't then validate certificates (think I want the `false` – or zero – value to be used for desirable defaults).

Finally, answering your question:

> But is it good coding practice to make use of this property and do not explicitly initialize your variable if it needs to be initialized with default value?

Yes, it is.

Answer (score 8):

Initialize variables to their zero values only if you want to use the short declaration syntax.

```
//less verbose than ''var count int''
count := 0
empty := ""
```

Otherwise, initializing them explicitly is just noise.
You might think that there's something wrong with uninitialized variables... and you'd be right. Fortunately, there's no such thing in go. Zero values are
part of the spec and they're not going to suddenly change.

Answer (score 6):

When a variable is declared it contains automatically the default `zero` or `null` value for its type: `0` for `int`, `0.0` for `float`, `false` for `bool`, empty string for `string`, `nil` for pointer, zero-ed struct, etc.

*All memory in Go is initialized!*.

For example: `var arr [5]int` in memory can be visualized as:

`+---+---+---+---+
 |   |   |   |   |
 +---+---+---+---+
   0   1   2   3`

When declaring an array, each item in it is automatically initialized with the default zero-value of the type, here all items default to 0.

So preferably it's better to initialize without default value, in other cases than the situations when you explicitly want to declare a variable with a default value.